# issue with useEffect understanding.Infinite loop runs when not passing any dependency array

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am fetching data inside `useEffect` and updating the local state when data arrives. But If I dont pass dependency array to `useEffect`, the state is updated but it runs infinite loop. On the other hand if I pass dependency array as empty or with state, then it does not update the state (i.e) data is not set into the local state variable from my axios request.

```
const [availableCars, setAvailableCars] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  postRequest(formData, headers).then((data) => {
    console.log('Vehicles Response:', data);
    console.log('Vehicles Response:', data.status);

    if (data.status == 'ok') {
      const vehiclesData = data.vehicles;
      setAvailableCars(vehiclesData);
    }
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: please share complete snippit ?  is your formData and headers simple JS Object or state Object ?  you might want to add formData and headers to dependency array

Comment: formData is simple JS object

Comment: did you `console.log(data.vehicles)`to see if it actually returns sth?

Comment: what is the values of data.status and vehiclesData when it runs the first time ? maybe console.log would help

Comment: @Apostolos yes. It returns data.

Comment: please share a fiddle

Comment: try copy the console logs to have them inside the 'if' statement as well. it might help understand where the problem is.

Comment: @RizwanAshraf What does the linter say about the effect? I assume you used create-creact-app so the browser console probably has warnings about missing dependencies. I also wonder where formdata and headers come from, can they change and do you need to make the request again when they change?

Comment: So @RizwanAshraf any updates on your question?

Answer (score 0):

You are causing an infinite loop of re-rerendering because you are always setting the response data in the state, even if it did not change, which in turn causes a re-render, then you assign to the state again, and the loop continues.

What you need to do is check for the received data against what you have in the state, and only set it when they are different.

I have no idea what your `data` looks like, but you can do something like:

```
if (data.status == 'ok' && JSON.stringify(data.vehicles) !== JSON.stringify(availableCars)) {
    setAvailableCars(data.vehicles);
}
```

I am using JSON's [stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) here because equality between objects is done by reference in JavaScript. If you don't want to use that, you can use [isEqual()](https://lodash.com/docs/2.4.2#isEqual)
from Lodash.

Comment: but the problem is why with [] as dep it doesnt even update the state at least once after the promise. I think we need a fiddle and not try to understand from this snippet what is going wrong with this code.

Answer (score -1):

What happens is due to the differences in component life cycle which were united in functional component under the useEffect hook.

Try this I hope it will solve the issue:

```
const [availableCars, setAvailableCars] = useState([]);
const [ready, setReady] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if(ready === false) {
      postRequest(formData, headers).then((data) => {
          console.log('Vehicles Response:', data);
          console.log('Vehicles Response:', data.status);
        
          if (data.status == 'ok') {
               const vehiclesData = data.vehicles;
               setAvailableCars(vehiclesData);
          }
      });
      setReady(true);
  }
}, [ready]);
```

Comment: i don't think this is the issue

Comment: this answer isn't relevant i think. maybe out of the context.

Comment: unless he posts sth extra regarding his issue, we cannot help him further. Unless he already solved it via another way and didnt update the status of his post.